# How to put MainView into maximized

Tags: qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

[using ubuntu sdk to write an application for the desktop]

Is there a way to change the window state of the [MainView](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.Components.MainView/)?

```
MainView {
    ...

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        Button {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: units.gu(30)
            height: units.gu(10)
            text: "Maximize this window"

            onClicked: {
                // Do something that maximizes the window
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To maximize your window, given that your target is a desktop app, I would rely on standard shortcuts like a double click on the title bar. Of course there's the window decoration controls too.

To start maximized, you can use the Screen properties:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    border.color: "lime"
    border.width: 15
    color: "transparent"
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: Screen.width + " x " + Screen.height
        font.bold: true
        font.pointSize: 80
        color: "lime"
        smooth: true
    }
}
```

Only Qt5.1 offers fine control on such window operations though: Visit http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qml-qtquick-window2-window.html#visibility-prop

Alternatively to maximize the view, you can export a C++ function that will call [QWidget::showMaximized()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#showMaximized) for you and then call it from QML.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `visibility`:

```
visibility: "Maximized"
```

The [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#visibility-prop) reads as:

> `visibility : QWindow::Visibility`
>
> The screen-occupation state of the window.
>
> **Visibility is whether the window should appear in the windowing system
>   as normal, minimized, maximized, fullscreen or hidden**.
>
> To set the visibility to AutomaticVisibility means to give the window
>   a default visible state, which might be fullscreen or windowed
>   depending on the platform. However when reading the visibility
>   property you will always get the actual state, never
>   AutomaticVisibility.
>
> When a window is not visible its visibility is Hidden, and setting
>   visibility to Hidden is the same as setting visible to false.

Also, know [the possible values](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwindow.html#Visibility-enum) for this attribute.